# Single Schedule Multiple entry in ODI

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am scheduling in mapping. This is steps i have taken.

1. create a scenario of the mapping

2.Create schedule of the scenario.

```
 i. in Definition-

      a. Context: Global

      b. Log Level: 5

      c. Status: Active

 ii. Execution style-

      a. Repetition: Many Times, Interval between repetition: 1 minutes
```

Now, when i go to schedule window of Agent, i see two schedule active for the same mapping. Why?. Isn't there should be only one schedule here.

I see only one schedule in agent only if do the changes on Definition and keep Execution style empty.

Tool: ODI 12c

Images: [Issue images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAvl8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the third part of your picture, in Schedule, that on the column Start time, the time is different for the two lines. There you can see all your runnings.

So, you don't have two schedule, but one that was run two times in the same day.

Comment: Thanks Lazarescu. I have setup that scenario to run every 1 minute. So it is showing next two instance i think. Do you know if it is supposed to show always next two instance?